# Is it correct to report R^2 value for simple time series trend analyses?

Tags: time-series, r-squared, trend, reporting

I am wondering if it makes sense to report an *R^2* value for a simple trend analysis. For example, trends in temperature or stream flow over time. I understand that for linear regression *R^2* makes sense in that it is an estimate of how well the variance in *y* is explained by changes in *x* i.e., how well your line of best fit predicts the actual data. However, for time series *x* (time) is not really the explanatory variable. That is, trend analysis is more of a correlative measure or descriptive statistic and so how well time explains changes in *y* does not make sense. Is that correct?

The internet seems to think that trend analysis and regression are the same thing but that is not what I have been told in the past. Unfortunately, I can't find, or don't currently have access to, an authoritative reference that can provide me with some insight.

This question comes from using a function in some software that can calculate a trend line much like Excel's trend line function (linear, polynomial etc) but it does not provide an R^2 value. Another user expects an R^2 value and I was surprised at the expectation. There is a regression package that does give the required metrics for proper reporting of regression results including *R^2*. Should we be adding in an *R^2* value for the function or is that really just a regression metric versus a trend metric.

So, two questions:

1. Should I be providing an R^2 metric for trend analysis (time series data).
2. Is there an authoritative reference for it, ideally publicly
   accessible (internet).

Comment: What would you want this calculation to tell you?

Comment: @Dave, good question. So, for me it has always been - yep/nope there is a trend. It has never been a predictive question. That is, I am not interested in forecasting out past the data to see what stream flows are going to be 10 years from now, if that is what you are asking. But I can see how that would influence my question.

Comment: There are two fundamental problems to be overcome: (1) $R^2$ needs careful re-interpretation when the responses (y values) are correlated, as is likely in a time series. (2) The longer you wait, the larger $R^2$ is likely to become.  I have seen a huge number of (peer-reviewed scientific) publications ignore both issues to make untenable claims about trends.  Of course you can always *report* $R^2,$ but when you do you could (greatly) improve on those second-rate publications by offering a clear, supportable interpretation for your readers.